# firebase_auth can't install new version

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to install `firebase_auth` in my flutter project. To install `flutter pub add firebase_auth` I am using command. It installs `firebase_auth` package but installs version `^0.15.4`. It does not install the new version and naturally causes conflicts.

I'm getting an output like this:

```
[simto_todolist] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in simto_todolist...                   1.084ms
exit code 0

--

[simto_todolist] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in simto_todolist...                  
Cannot create link, path = 'C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\_temp\dir20230c53\ios\Classes\FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m' (Operating System Error: Not granted by required privileges.
, errno = 1314)
pub get failed (66; , errno = 1314))
exit code 66
```

What is the problem? How can I solve it? Thank you very much in advance for the help.

Answer (score -1):

**You can set in manual by editing your pubspec.yaml project file**

```
  firebase_auth:
```

**when you remove version from your file pub will install latest version**

Comment: Error: `* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Project with path ':app' could not be found in project ':firebase_auth'.`